# Overriding full screen f11 browser button to launch Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fullscreen

I was wondering if it was possible to override the f11 button to make it that instead of the browser becoming full screen. An element within the browser becomes full screen. The element is an Iframe within. 
To be more specific, the element is a slide show presentation within a web page that does have a button that allows it to become full screen. But I would like to make it that f11 can also make the slide show full screen.

Comment: Don't do that; it's counter-intuitive. What's wrong with a separate "full screen" button like the one in your favourite video site?

Comment: I already added a button for full screen however I felt like it would be perhaps more simple to tie the f11 button to the function added in the button to streamline things a little.